# Dropdown List Value From SQL in PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I want to do this function in php. i have two fields, one is text box and an
other one is drop down list. Drop down list contains values from sql. When one of the value is selected from the drop down list i want the text box to be filled according to the option which is selected.

Following is the drop down list code,

```
<td>Test Group ID</td>
 <td><select id="testgroupid" name="testgroupid" style="column-width:35">
  <option value="<?php echo $testgroupid;?>"><?php echo $testgroupid;?></option>
   <?php 
   $x=new con();
   $x->connect();
   $retval = "select distinct(Id) from testgroupmaster";
   $sql1 = mysql_query($retval) or die (mysql_error());
   while($res=mysql_fetch_array($sql1, MYSQL_BOTH)){
    ?> 
<option value="<?=$res['Id'];?>"><?=$res['Id'];?></option>
<?
}
?>
  </select></td>
```

According to the id,I want textbox to be filled, How can i do this ? Pls help friends.

```
<tr>
<td>Test Group Name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="testgroupname" id="zipsearch" value="<?php echo $testgroupname; ?> "></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: <option value="<?=$res['Id'];?>"><?=$res['Id'];?></option>both text and value given same

Answer (score 0):

If you want your textbox to be filled immediately after the dropdown selection changes, the simplest way is to use javascript:

```
<td><select id="testgroupid" name="testgroupid" style="column-width:35" 
   onchange='document.getElementsByName("testgroupname")[0].value =   
    document.getElementById("testgroupid").options[e.selectedIndex].value;'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need JavaScript for that. Use jQuery (or your favorite library) and bind an event listener to the combobox.

Example with jQuery:

```
$("#myCombo").change(function(e){
    $("myTextField").val( $("#myCombo").val() );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have one suggestion which involves jQuery. I do not know if you are using this library, but I am posting it anyway :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
         $("#testgroupid").change(function{
            $("#zipsearch").text($(this option:selected).val();
         });
     });
</script>
```

On change event on the dropbown-box, this function fires, and sets the zipsearch-input accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where $testgroupname comes from but I take it you would like to get that value upon selection in the dropdown. If you don´t have the value available on the client you have to retrieve it from the server somehow.

You can´t use PHP to fill the text box since you do not send your posts when an options is selected in the dropdown. There are many alternatives on how to solve this. I would personally use Ajax to fill the textbox without posting to server.

Good place to start:
http://buffernow.com/2012/08/cascading-dropdown-ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<script>
    function selecteditem(selectedval)
    {
        jQuery.post("<?php echo JURI::root().'test.php'?>", { id: selectedval },
        function(data) {
            jQuery('.zipsearch').val(data);      
        });
    }
</script>


//test.php on the root
<?php 
    $val=$_POST['id'];

    //do what you want with $val 
    //and say final output is in variable $result than echo it

    echo $result;
?>


<!--html code here-->

<select id="testgroupid" name="testgroupid" style="column-width:35" onclick="selecteditem(this.value);">
    <option value="<?php echo $testgroupid;?>"><?php echo $testgroupid;?></option>
    <?php 
        $x=new con();
        $x->connect();
        $retval = "select distinct(Id) from testgroupmaster";
        $sql1 = mysql_query($retval) or die (mysql_error());
        while($res=mysql_fetch_array($sql1, MYSQL_BOTH))
        {
            ?> 
            <option value="<?=$res['Id'];?>"><?=$res['Id'];?></option>
            <?
        }
    ?>
</select>


<input type="text" name="testgroupname" id="zipsearch" class="zipsearch" value="<?php echo $testgroupname; ?> ">
```

Comment: its working well but i am getting the id value in the text box but not testgroup name. @Tornado

Comment: So you want testgroupname value according to what id is selected isn't it?

Comment: Then you have to pass that value using `jQuery.post()` and after that you have to get that value using `$_POST` and then pass it to `jQuery('.zipsearch').val(test);`

Comment: i dont much about jquery. Could you pls help? @Tornado

Comment: Ok Thank you, I try that :) and let you know the result :) @Tornado

Answer (score 0):

html

```
  <select id="testgroupid" name="testgroupid" 
style="column-width:35" onChange=filltext();>
```

javascript

```
function filltext()
{
 var e = document.getElementById("testgroupid");
 var group = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
document.getElementById("zipsearch").value= group ;



}
```

your php code is wrong here

```
<option value="<?=$res['Id'];?>"><?=`$res['Id']`;?></option>
```

change to

```
<option value="<?=$res['Id'];?>"><?=$res['GROUP_NAME'];?></option>
```

Comment: Test group name is not filled instead its id value in the text box @Arun Killu

Comment: check your code what is the point in giving value and text the same..in option

Comment: The reason is, I use this option value to fetched on the text box on edit function. @Arun Killu

Comment: you can get the id from option value for that there is no need giving it two time in value and text.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// Assume $db is a PDO object

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=populatedropdown', "root", "");

$query = $dbh->query("select * from position"); // Run your query

echo '<form action="populate.php" method="get" name="send3">';
echo '<select name="populate">'; // Open your drop down box



// Loop through the query results, outputing the options one by one
while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   echo '<option value="'.$row['name'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
}

echo '</select>';// Close your drop down box

echo '</form>';

?>

<script language="JavaScript">
         function send_input1(){            
          document.send1.input4.value = document.send3.populate.value;
          }
</script>

<form name="send1" action=javascript:send_input1()>
<p><input type=submit value=Enter>
</p><input size=30 name="input4">
</form>
```